# Getting path alias on the base of term id

Tags: 7, path-aliases

Foolowing is the code to display breadcrumb, it will display the results like this `Parent1/Parent2/Parent3/..`

```
$var1=taxonomy_get_parents_all("term_id");
for($j=sizeof(intval($var1)) ; $j>=0 ;$j--)
{
  print $var1[$j]->name."/";
}
```

Here I want to compute the path alias for each parent, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To get the alias of a term : `drupal_get_path_alias('taxonomy/term/[tid]')`.

**Just a suggestion :** To print the `breadcrumbs` you should try [Custom Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module.